# Keep value in form only after validation fails

Tags: php, forms

I want to keep the username in the form when the validation fails. This works for that, but the problem is that it also keeps the username in the form after success. How can I solve this?

```
public function RegisterForm(){
    if (isset($_SESSION['m_username'])&& isset($_POST[$this->m_username])){
        $_SESSION['m_username'] = $_POST[$this->m_username];
    } else {
        $_SESSION['m_username'] = "";
    }
    return
    '<form method="post">
           <label class=label>Username:</label> 
           <input type="text" name="'.$this->m_username.'" value="'.$_SESSION['m_username'].'" />
           ........     
     </form>';

}
```

Comment: you should unset the session after the form success.

Comment: I have tried that but it does not work.

Comment: @ana In conjunction with `Hasina's` comment, you need to include `session_start();`, otherwise your `$_SESSION`'s won't work. Or, did you leave that out?